# Selecting Pandas DF between two values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to subset a column of values that were extracted from a correlation matrix. I want to get values greater than 0.75 and less than -0.75. I tried the first line of code and it only gave me positive values greater than 0.75. The second line of code error'd out without a result.

`Corr_matrix1 = Corr_matrix1[(Corr_matrix1['Coefficient'] >= abs(0.75))]`

`Corr_matrix1 = Corr_matrix1 [(Corr_matrix1 ['Coefficient'] >= 0.75) & (Corr_matrix1 ['Coefficient'] <= -0.75)]`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you paste the error you are getting?

Comment: The mistake is that you don't want values that are less than -x *and* greater than x, you want values that are less than -x *or* greater than x. This is the correct logic, your version returns no matches for x>0.

Comment: Pygri, thanks, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the DataFrame.query method, one of my favorite features of pandas and it's pretty slept on. Here's an example;

```
df.corr().query(
'Coefficient <= -0.75'
'or Coefficient >= 0.75'
)
```

It's kind of odd, you pass the arguments as strings without commas in between multiple arguments. If you use a variable, you can use an f string.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Interval Index
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html